# How do I add a button that plays audio onclick in Chrome Extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am building a simple Chrome Extension pop-up that involves playing audio by clicking on a button. While the `html5` tag for `<audio controls>` works fine, I was looking for a way to discard the default setup provided by `html5` and customize the layout instead. Now here is where the problem lies: I now have a button, but it does not play any audio when I click on it.

**popup.html**

```
<audio id="my-audio" src="chrome-extension://[MY_ID]/audios/rain.mp3" type="audio/mp3"></audio>
<button id="play">Play</button>
```

**popup.js**

```
let myAudio = document.getElementById('my-audio');
let playButton = document.getElementById('play');

playButton.addEventListener("click", function(){
    myAudio.play()
});
```

**manifest.json**

```
{
  "name": ...,
  "description": ...,
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "background": {
    "service_worker": "background.js"
  },
  "permissions": ["storage", "activeTab", "scripting"],
  "action": {
    "default_popup": "popup.html",
    "host_permissions": ["<all_urls>"],
  },
}
```

My `background.js` is currently empty, and no errors are shown when I run the extension. I used my extension ID to access the audio file, which worked well when I used the `<audio>` tag.

Any help with identifying the problem would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can inspect the pop-up console by right-clicking on your extension's icon and selecting "Inspect pop-up". See if there are any errors there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably facing the classic "egg and chicken" problem :-)
When you trying to play the audio file this latter is not ready yet to be played.
Wrap the popup.js code inside a DomContentLoaded event handler.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion! I added the following to `popup.js`: `function play() { playButton.addEventListener("click", function(){ myAudio.play()})};

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", play());` However, the result is still the same as before :(

Comment: keep DOMContentLoaded event handller a try with:   document.getElementById('my-audio').play()

Comment: Also make this mod:   document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", play)   You have to inspect your popup to check for errors.